# How to expose jQuery native / local scope to variables to extend object methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom, scope

Alright maybe this question has been answered before but I don't even really know how to ask it. All I can tell you what I'm trying to do.

I create an array of document objects with jQuery selector function and assign it to a variable like so:

```
    var imgArray = $("#rootContainer > img");
```

now when i iterate over the array all of the jQuery methods are gone. For instance this doesn't work.

```
   for (i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
       var scaledWidth = (imgArray[i].width * 0.5); 
       imgArray[i].width(scaledWidth);
    }
```

error something like width is not a function... which it's not in the standard DOM but if jQuery scope was passed to the variable it would be. I can get the code to work in pure javascript but then whats the point of abstracting away the DOM if you can't pass scope?

Comment: try `$(imgArray).eq(i).width(scaledWidth);` if u have error `not a function` wrap variable inside jquery selector.

Comment: what does ".eq(i)" do

Comment: eq(2) same as in js arr[2], acces to second array item

Answer (score 0):

i know three ways to get needed element from array `$(selector)[index]`, `$(selector).get(index)`, `$(selector).eq(index)`...and u can use `foreach`

```
$.foreach(imgArray,function (index, img){
     scaledWidth = (img.width() * 0.5); 
     img.width(scaledWidth);
});


for (i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
   var img = $(imgArray)[i],
       scaledWidth = (img.width() * 0.5); 
   img.width(scaledWidth);
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that jQuery would hand back all of its methods to the variable. is it stripped of jQuery's scope when its handed back to the variable? My variable imgArray only has native elements in order to use jQuerys methods I have to pass it back into scope with $(imgArray)?.. sorry jQuery noob alert.

Comment: Variable img using like container for current image $(imgArray)[i], this used to less code and you can don't use this variable and write directly $(imgArray)[i], sorry i don't understand that you say about scope...

Answer (score 0):

When you have a jQuery instance, you can call jQuery methods. When you have a single DOM node, you can use the native DOM API, and call DOM methods and set DOM properties, but you cannot use jQuery methods on regular DOM elements.

Here you will find more detailed information:

http://james.padolsey.com/stuff/jQueryBookThing/#dom-then-jquery